# Confused about big-O notation (specific example)

Tags: c++, big-o, time-complexity

We did an exercise in class today dealing with big-O notation. Here is one of the problems:

```
void modifyArray(int a[], int size)
{   
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size / 2; ++i)
    {
        if (max < a[i])
        max = a[i];
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= size * size; ++j)
    {
        ++max;
        cout << max;
    }
}
```

My intuition tells me that f(n) = n/2 + n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>) but according to my professor the answer is simply O(n).  Could anyone explain to me why and when we just change what we consider to be the input size?

I understand that it is not a nested loop -- that is not what is confusing me. I don't understand why for a given input `size`, the second loop is only considered to be O(n). The only way I can make sense of this is if we isolate the second loop and then redefine the input size to simply being n = size^2.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Because you can remove the second loop and simply write `max += size * size`

Comment: Well the code in the question is clearly O(n^2), but after optimization it's O(n). However, did the professor say anything about that?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I really like your lines of thinking; however, I interpreted the exercise instructions as taking the code at face value, regardless of how "useless" (or inefficient, for that matter) the code seemed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code you present is exactly the code your professor is commenting on, then (s)he's *wrong*.  As written, it outputs each number from 1 to `size * size`, which is definitely O(n^2), as n = size is the sane choice.

Yes, you're right to think you could say something like "O(n) where n is the square of the array size", but that's complication without purpose.

As others have said, if the `cout << max` is removed, the compiler *may* optimise out the loop to a single O(1) assignment, meaning the function's other O(n) operation dictates the overall big-O efficiency, but it *may not* - who said you're even enabling optimisation?  The best way to to describe the big-O efficiency is therefore to say "if optimisation kicks in then O(n) else O(n^2)" - it's not useful to assert one or the other then hide your assumptions, and the consequences if they're wrong, in a footnote.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sequence of statements
}
for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    sequence of statements
}
```

The first loop is O(N) and the second loop is O(M). Since you don't know which is bigger, you say this is O(max(N,M)).

In your case N=size/2 and M=size*size.

O(max(N,M)) becomes O(max(size/2,size*size)) which is O(size*size).
so f(n)=O(size^2)=O(n^2)

for the problem you are asking;
yeah i think, what you think is correct. **redefine the input size to simply being n = size^2.** that should be the way to consider it as O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the second loop can be done away with.

If you do not consider outputting intermediate terms, then

```
It is equivalent to max += size*size.
```

Then the code complexity shall reduce to `O(size/2) ~ O(size)`.